# Spring data mongodb federation attempts -- how can I get interface methods to use a custom configured mongotemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my application, I need to be able to connect to any number of mongodb hosts, and any number of databases in any of those hosts to support at least this basic level of query federation.  This is specified by configuration, so, for any given installation of our app, I cannot know ahead of time how many collections I will need to access.  I based my attempt on configuration that I saw in [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-multiple-databases-spring-data) with some modifications to suit my requirements.  My configuration looks something like this yaml:

```
datasources:
  - name: source1
    uri: mongodb://user1:pass1@127.0.0.1:27017
    fq_collection: db1.coll1
  - name: source2
    uri: mongodb://user1:pass1@192.168.0.100:27017
    fq_collection: db2.coll2
```

And, depending on the installation, there could be any number of datasources entries.  So, in my @Configuration class, I can iterate through these entries that are injected via configuration properties.  But I want to create a MongoTemplate that I can set up for each of these, since I cannot rely on the default MongoTemplate.  The solution that I have attempted is to create a repository interface, and then to create a custom impl that will accept the configured MongoTemplate.  When I use this code to create each Repository instance with its template:

```
public MongoRepository<String, Item> mongoCustomRepositories(MongoTemplate template) {
    MyCustomMongoRepository customImpl = new MyCustomMongoRepositoryImpl(template);
    MongoRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory = new MongoRepositoryFactory(template);
    return repositoryFactory.getRepository(MyMongoRepository.class, customImpl);
}
```

And I call it from a @Bean method that returns the list of all of these repositories created from the config entries, I can inject the repositories into service classes.

UPDATE/EDIT: Ok, I set mongodb profiling to 2 in order to log the queries.  It turns out that, in fact, the queries *are* being sent to mongodb, but the problem is that the collection names are not being set for the model.  I can't believe that I forgot about this, but I did, so it was using the lower camel case model class name, which will make sure that there are no documents to be retrieved.  I have default collection names, but the specific collection names are set in the configuration, like the example YAML shows.  I have a couple of ideas, but if anyone has a suggestion about how to set these dynamically, then that would help a lot.

EDIT 2: I did a bunch of work and I have it *almost* working.  However, in doing this, I uncovered a bug in spring-data-mongodb, and I filed an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4231).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question will come when https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/4231 is resolve and the corresponding release becomes available.